# How to zoom out in Selenium WebDriver to 50% of 1920x1080 screen resolution?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm currently really new to automation and am using Selenium WebDriver, Capybara and Cucumber for automating our tests. Could someone help me with how to go about zooming out 50% of my current screen of 1920x1080?

Comment: check out the sendkeys method https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#sendkeys

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

My team's solution was to add a resolution property to our Selenium WebDriver snippet with dimensions of 2560x1440 in order to have a larger view of elements to target its xpaths.

If there's a better way, I am open to learning more.